# Speedup python code operations on CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

**Problem Description:**

I have a module which reads `.csv` file and sums up the column value using `numpy.sum(axis=0)`.

This is module is called for every n `.csv` files. For now, I am performing this operation for over 12,000 `.csv` files and it takes a total of 11-20  minutes. For reading the file, I am using python's `with open`.

**Question:**
Will reading `.csv` files using pandas and performing `numpy.sum` help me to reduce the execution time or is there any other way to speed up the process?

Comment: Processing data from disk takes time. You may just have to deal with it. But we can't help you without seeing your code. Please read [ask].

Comment: Also try to isolate the smallest snippet of code which is the main bottle neck as the performance issue you describe is too general, and edit your question with this snippet